# Is there any way to replace for loop to Multiple-threading for speedy time execution?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-multithreading

For a detailed understanding, I have attached a link of file.

[Indetail understanding code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_qHGRkoW68uJ__IRRxtZwUCOMI_ollc_?usp=sharing)

I have data in the list, that has similar syntax like:

```
i = [a.b>c.d , e.f.g>h.i.j ]
l = [a.b , e.f.g ]
n = [a.b>c.d , e.f.g ]
```

e.g. Each element of the list has multiple sub-elements separated by "." and ">"

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
reac={}
reag={}
t = l[i].split(">")
REAC = t[0]
Reac = REAC.split(".")

for o in range(len(Reac)):

    reaco = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/" + Reac[o]

    respo = requests.get(reaco)
    reac[o] ={"Smile":Reac[o],"Details" :respo.json()}

if (len(t) != 1):
    REAG = t[1]
    Reag = REAG.split(".")
    for k in range(len(Reag)):

        reagk = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/" + Reag[k]
        repo = requests.get(reagk)
        reag[k] = {"Smile": Reag[k], "Details" :repo.json()}
    res = {"Reactants": list(reac.values()), "Reagents": list(reag.values())}
    boo.append(res)
else:
    res = {"Reactants": list(reac.values()), "Reagents": "No reagents"}
    boo.append(res)
```

We have separated all the elements and for each element, we are calling 3rd party API. That consumes too much time.

Is there any way to reduce this time and optimize for the loop?

It takes around 1 minute to respond. We want to optimize to 5-10 seconds.

Comment: if the external API takes 1 minute then the closest you can reach to reducing your io time is 1 minute. you can't reduce it to 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can start multiple requests and process them when they are finished with
[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).
That might speed it up a bit.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: True, but i dont have the reputation to comment :)

Comment: @Robert_Hall you can add your suggestion in google colab 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_qHGRkoW68uJ__IRRxtZwUCOMI_ollc_?usp=sharing